# when using two images for background not working in safari

Tags: safari, background-image

I'm using two images for a background image. (two quote marks that bookend)

When I use just one image it works in Safari. When I try this CSS with two images, doesn't work in Safari anymore. Does work in Firefox though.

background:transparent url(../images/quote.png) no-repeat left top,
url(../images/quote2.png) no-repeat right bottom 25px;

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
background: url(../images/quote.png) top left no-repeat, 
            url(../images/quote2.png) right bottom 25px no-repeat;
```

You can only specify the background-color for the last (middle) layer. In this case your `transparent` isn't necessary anyway. If you are looking to reset other CSS, put a `background-color: transparent;` before this line.

Bear in mind this is not supported in all browsers. A better option would be to wrap the element in a container div/span. Apply one background to the element and the other to the container div/span.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the advice. I had tried your div suggestion earlier, and it didn't work out. But, I did end up still using it. There was just one change that seemed to matter to Safari. It didn't seem to like the positioning I had defined of:
 right bottom 25px no-repeat 
Specifically the right and bottom.

Here is what I ended up using and it worked. Might be a matter of the flexslider interacting. Not sure. But this did work. Thank you again.

```
.flexslider { margin: 0; padding: 0 0 0 25px; background:transparent url(../images/quote.png) no-repeat left top; } 

.flexslider .slides #test-text{ background: url(../images/quote2.png) no-repeat 345px 96px; }
```